# MySQL - Select only first 3 or 2 Characters (non - numeric) values from string using REGEXP

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone tell me how to get the whole string which is start from characters?

```
Like 
SKU: 12345
SKU: ABC12345
SKU: AB12345
SKU: xyz12345
SKU: xy12345
```

I want to get SKU: ABC12345 and xyz12345 because its have 3 character in the start by using REGEXP in mysql.

I want to get SKU: AB12345 and xy12345 because its have 2 character in the start by using REGEXP in mysql.

Can anyone let me know how can i get both these?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following pattern should help:

```
...
WHERE sku REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]{2,3}([^a-zA-Z]|$)'
...
```

It matches two or three alphabetic letters (`[a-zA-Z]{2,3}`) at the beginning (`^`) followed by a character, that isn't an alphabetic letter (`[^a-zA-Z]`) or the end of the string (`$`).